# Executing a file using a Python script

Tags: python

I don't have a clue on where to look for a solution to this. Basically i want to make a file that can be "opened with" a python script. The directory of the opened file will be stored as a variable in the script. Here's what I mean by "Open With": [image]

Sorry if I'm not too good at describing this.

Comment: Do you want to open `.phktest` file with `c:\some\path\phktestrunner.py` or you want to open it with only `python`?

Comment: i want to open `.phktest` with the Python FILE, not Python itself. It would be nice if I could store the full path of the `.phktest` file being opened as a variable. i.e. `C:\!PythonCode2\runfileswith\test.phktest`

Comment: By Python FILE you meant a file with `.py` extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a more direct way, but one approach could be to write a simple batch file that invokes the Python interpreter with your script:

**`main.bat`**

```
@echo off
python main.py %1
```

Add absolute or relative paths if necessary.

Within `main.py`, the name of the file should then be available as `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: This does technically work, but I'm not able to see any Python errors, because the console closes immediately. I've tried adding `/K` to the `.bat` file but still nothing

Comment: Add `pause` at the end of the batch file, after the `python` command line.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding, what you want is your argv[1] be 'C:!PythonCode2\runfileswith\test.phktest'.

I did some test on my Windows 10, simply drag the `.phktest` file onto the `main.py` will let sys.argv[1] be the full path of that file!